# frozen screen after Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, permissions

I have just upgraded to 14.4 ubuntu version.
it boots fine, but the screen immediately freezes.
I booted from live CD and navigated to my Documents and tried to copy them to an external hard drive but got error that, I haven't got permission to copy the directory.
How can I gain access to finish this task before doing anything?

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you open/read the files you intend to copy? Can you create a new (empty) file in the destination directory? Please [edit] your question to improve it with additional info.

Comment: Thanks David, Yeah I can do all of that, and select / copy, but when I come to paste to the destination, then I have got the error that, I don't have permission.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have inexplicable permission issues with Nautilus too – especially on file systems that aren't unixoid (NTFS or CIFS). In these situations I usually resort to the command line. To copy a whole directory tree recursively, you need to issue:

```
cp -R [SOURCE] [DESTINATION]
```

Alternatively you can try other file managers like [Thunar](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/thunar) [image: Install Thunar] or [Dolphin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dolphin) [image: Install Dolphin].